# Symfony form type choice field boolean always true

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have entity with property reverse, type boolean and form for this property type choice - checkbox and always after form handleRequest I have `true` why not understand, if check box not checked have `"0"` but after submit form have `true`

```
    /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reversed_vat", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default"=0})
 */
private $reversedVat;

  /**
 * Set reversedVat
 *
 * @param boolean $reversedVat
 *
 * @return OutboundInvoice
 */
public function setReversedVat($reversedVat)
{
    $this->reversedVat = (boolean)$reversedVat;

    return $this;
}
```

In form I create data transformer with check property but in transfomer I have true

```
/**
 * Get reversedVat
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getReversedVat()
{
    return (boolean)$this->reversedVat;
}

    $builder
        ->add('reversedVat', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false])

        $builder->get('reversedVat')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function($mypropertyAsBoolean) {

            },
            function($mypropertyAsString) {
                $r = $mypropertyAsString;//have always true
            }
        ));
```

if I not checked still have true after form handleRequest  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataTransformer is not necessary.
CheckBoxType has transformer functionality in itself.

ReversedVat property is simply below.

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(name="reversed_vat", type="boolean", nullable=false, options={"default"=0})
 */
private $reversedVat = false;

/**
 * @param bool $reversedVat
 * @return Temp
 */
public function setReversedVat($reversedVat)
{
    $this->reversedVat = $reversedVat;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function getReversedVat()
{
    return $this->reversedVat;
}
```

Confirm boolean is set to *$reversedVat* as default value.

And the form type is below.

```
$builder
    ->add('reversedVat', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using symfony >= 4.1, in your form type use false_values option.

```
$builder->add('reversedVat', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false, 'false_values' => ['false', '0']])
```

Comment: Looks like in 3.4 there is no such option https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html

Comment: false_values option is available from symfony 4.1 and above.